# Lists in recursive function

Tags: python, list, recursion

I want to get access to lists, that are created while recursion, but I only get access to the first one.

```
my_data = [1,2,3,4,5]

def my_function (some_data):
    some_list = []
    for i in range(len(some_data)-1):
        some_list.append(some_data[i+1]+some_data[i])

    if len(some_list)>1:
        my_function(some_list)

    return some_list[0]

forty_eight = my_function(my_data)
```

so the idea is that during first step I get sum of each neighbor elements, so I get [3,5,7,9], next I get [8,12,16], then [20, 28] and the at last I get [48].

Because last list has single element I want to return it to variable named "forst_eight", but the problem is, that this variable equals three. Which means when after the return command the program uses first list i've created, not the last. 
What shoulf I do to make forty_eight be equal to 48?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to return your recursion call `return my_function(some_list)`. This is important because you call `my_function` again and again, till your break condition is true, BUT you never return the value, so only the initial list is really used.

```
my_data = [1,2,3,4,5]

def my_function (some_data):
    some_list = []
    for i in range(len(some_data)-1):
        some_list.append(some_data[i+1]+some_data[i])

    if len(some_list)>1:
        return my_function(some_list)

    return some_list[0]

forty_eight = my_function(my_data)
print forty_eight # >>> 48
```

Comment: thank you very much, still dont understand why it works. Will try find info.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling your inner  function, but you are not using its output. You probably should

```
 if len(some_list)>1:
     return my_function(some_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Other people have addressed the specific issues with your current implementation. I'm posting this answer just to offer an alternative approach towards your goal of recursively summing neighbouring elements in a list that you might find a little clearer.

```
def sum_reduce(l):
    if len(l) == 1:
        return l[0]
    else:
        summed_neighbours = [a + b for a, b in zip(l[:-1], l[1:])]
        print(summed_neighbours)
        return sum_reduce(summed_neighbours)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Result: ', sum_reduce([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

**Output**

```
[3, 5, 7, 9]
[8, 12, 16]
[20, 28]
[48]
Result:  48
```